# Is it possible to see the CODE for sp_executesql? Is it TSQL?

Tags: sql-server

Is it possible to see the CODE for sp_executesql? 
I would like to see the actual code. 
I could not find it in sql server management studio.

Answer (score 4):

sp_executesql is an extended stored procedure. It's binary in a DLL.